# ldap_sasl_bind - GSSAPI for NTLM authentication

Tags: active-directory, ntlm, gssapi

Does [ldap_sasl_bind_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support NTLM authentication via GSSAPI? It seems that this is variable to the underlying implementation ([GSSAPI for NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411099/gssapi-for-ntlm-authentication)). I am trying to use NTLM authentication to an Active Directory server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the method call says: this is SASL's problem. You have to specify the SASL mechanism. The GSSAPI mechanism is Kerberos 5. Some GSS-APIs like Heimdal do support NTLM but your SASL impl has to do that too, I guess. I do not think that Cyrus SASL does that. It's best to rely on GSS-API with Kerberos only. This work here from a C SASL bind and a Java SASL bind.

Comment: It seems for AD LDS, the SASL bind requests goes directly to Windows SSPI (which from my understanding support NTLM). http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816913(v=ws.10)

Comment: @DanielHwang, yes this is correct. Windows relies on its own SASL implementation with SSPI in the background.